# Quadratic Variation of Brownian motion martingale

Tags: martingales, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion and let $M_t = B_t^2 -t$.

I want to show that $[M]=[B^2]$. Therefore I want to use the linearity of quadratic variations
\begin{align}
[\alpha X + \beta Y, Z] = \alpha[X,Z] + \beta [Y,Z].
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
[M]_t &= [B^2 - t]_t \\
&= [B^2 - t, B^2 - t]_t \\
&= [B^2, B^2 - t]_t - [ t, B^2 - t]_t \\
&= [B^2, B^2]_t - [ t, B^2]_t - \big( [ B^2, t]_t - [t,t] \big) \\
&= [B^2]_t -2 [ B^2, t]_t + [t].
\end{align}
How to find that $[M]_t = [B^2]_t$?

Comment: If $Y$ has paths of finite variation then $[X,Y]=0$.

Comment: Okay, since $t$ is a deterministic function $[B^2,t]$ and $[t]$ are 0.

Comment: @JohnDawkins may I know the linearity of quadratic variations is proven? How do we show $\left[\alpha X + \beta Y, Z\right] = \alpha\left[ X,Z \right] + \beta\left[ Y,Z \right]$? Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of  $[M]$?