# Quadratic Variation Brownian motion martingale (2)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion and $M_t = B_t^2 -t$. From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781078/quadratic-variation-of-brownian-motion-martingale) we are aware of the identity 
\begin{align}
[M]=[B^2].
\end{align}
Now, I want to apply Itô's formula to $B_t^2$ and from that find a representation for $[B^2]$ in terms of a single $ds$-integral to check that $M^2-[B^2]$ is a martingale, as it should.

However, applying Itô's formula
\begin{align}
f(B_t) = f(B_0) + \int_0^t f'(B_s) dB_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f''(B_s) ds
\end{align}
gives that
\begin{align}
B_t^2 &= B_0^2 + 2 \int_0^t B_s\ dB_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t 2 ds \\
B_t^2 &= 0 + [B_s^2]^{s=t}_{s=0} + [s]^{s=t}_{s=0}\\
B^2_t &= B^2_t +t 
\end{align}
Where is the mistake?

**Solution:**

By Itô's formula we find that
\begin{align}
2 \int_0^t B_s\ dB_s = B_t^2 - t = M_t.
\end{align}
From the fact that $[M]=[B^2]$ and $I(t) = 2 \int_0^t B_s\ dB_s$ is an Itô-integral. We find that
\begin{align}
[B^2]=[I]= 2 \int_0^t B_s^2\ ds.
\end{align}

Comment: the stochastic integral B_s dB_s is not B_t^2, but is a martingale, hence subtract t and you are finished.

Comment: So, $2 \int_0^t B_s dB_s = B_t^2 -t$ ?

Comment: Yes, this is what you (also) calculated.

Comment: From the calculations I see that is has to be true. But why is this the case? How to evaluate the stochastic integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comment, we usually do not have the formula $\int x dx = x^2/2$, if we replace the ordinary Lebesgue/Riemannian integral by the Itô integral, which is exactly the statement of Itô's lemma, as we have $df(B_t) = f'(B_t) dB_t + \frac{1}{2} f''(B_t) dt$. So in your case, if you are interested in calculating $f(B_s) dB_s$ for a differentiable function, you need the antiderivative of $f$, and on this antiderivative you can apply Itô's formula. For example, if you want to calculate $\cos(B_t) dB_t$, choose $f(x) = \sin(x)$, then by Itô's formula you have $\sin(B_t) - \sin(B_0) = \int_0^t \cos(B_t) dB_t - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \sin(B_t) dt$, or in your case you just need to consider $f(x) = x^2/2$.

On the other hand, if you want to prove that $B_t^2 - t$ is indeed a martingale (and hence the quadratic variation of $B_t$ is $t$), apply Itô's formula to $f(x) = x^2$, so you get $B_t^2 = 2 \int_0^t B_s dB_s + \int_0^t 1 dt$, so $B_t^2 - t = \int_0^t B_s dB_s$, which (in this particular case) is a martingale.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Comment: Shouldn't it be: $df(B_t) = f'(B_t)\ dB_t + \frac{1}{2}f''(B_t)\ dt$?

Comment: Okay I get this Itô-calculus! $\int_0^t B_s dB_s$ is not just integrating w.r.t. the variable $B_s$. You find this integral using Itô's formula!

Comment: Thanks, I have missed the $\frac{1}{2}$ in the general formula, I have edited it.

Comment: Exactly. Although it is of course intentional that $\int_0^t B_s dB_s$ looks like an integral, one should always remember that it is an $L^2(\mathbb{P})$ limit (or in a more general setting a stochastic limit). Thus one cannot deduce any pointwise properties, i.e. $\int_0^t B_s dB_s(\omega)$ is usually unknown. However, with the help of Itô's formula you can see that sometimes it is possible to derive a more explicit construction.

Comment: By the way, there is another stochastic integral, known as Stratonovich integral, which is closely related to the Itô integral, and usually denoted by $\int_0^t B_s \circ dB_s$. For this, there are similar formulae, but Itô's lemma has to be changed and looks more like the fundamental theorem of calculus, i.e. $B_t^2 = 2 \int_0^t B_s \circ dB_s$. It lacks the property of being a martingale, and is thus often not introduced.

Comment: Yes I read about that integral as well. Using the above result and again Itô's formula, do you see how to show that $M^2 - [B^2]$ is a martingale? (without appealing to the fact that $M^2 - [B^2]= M^2 - [M]$ is a martingale

Comment: I have created a new post for the question in the above comment.