# Brownian Motion Third Power Martingale using Ito Integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion and $M_t = B_t^2 - t$.

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1781078/quadratic-variation-of-brownian-motion-martingale) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784798/quadratic-variation-brownian-motion-martingale-2?lq=1) posts we know that
\begin{align}
[M] = [B^2] = 2 \int_0^t B_s^2\ ds. 
\end{align}
Now, without appealing to the fact that $M^2 - [B^2] = M^2 - [M]$ is a martingale by definition, I want to prove that $M^2 - [B^2]$ is a martingale using Itô's formula and the above result.

Therefore, I apply Itô's formula to $M_t^2 = (B_t^2 -t)^2 = f(t, B_t)$.
\begin{align}
f(t,B_t) &= f(0,B_0) + \int_0^t f_s'(s,B_s)\ ds + \int_0^t f_{B_s}'(s,B_s)\ dB_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f_{B_s,B_s}''(s,B_s) ds
\end{align}
gives that
\begin{align}
(B_t^2 -t)^2 &= -2 \int_0^t (B_s^2 -s)\ ds+ 4 \int_0^t B_s(B_s^2 -s)\ dB_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \big(4(B_s^2 - s) + 4B_s \cdot 2B_s \big) ds \\
&= -2 \int_0^t B_s^2\ ds + 2 \int_0^t s\ ds + 4 \int_0^t B_s^3\ dB_s -4 \int_0^t s B_s\ dB_s + 6 \int_0^t B_s^2\ ds -2 \int_0^t s\ ds \\
&= 4 \int_0^t B_s^2\ ds + 4 \int_0^t B_s^3\ dB_s -4 \int_0^t s B_s\ dB_s.
\end{align} 
So, subtracting $2 \int_0^t B_s^2\ ds$ from $(B_t^2 -t)^2$ should give the required result. However, there is a problem with the coefficients. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Where is the problem? The preceding posts indicate that $[M]_t=4\int_0^tB_s^2ds$ and your computations here confirm exactly that.

Comment: I have found that $[M] = [B^2] = 2 \int_0^t B_s^2\ ds$ instead of $4 \int_0^t B_s^2\ ds$.

Comment: Yeah, and you should wonder how $dM=2BdB+Ydt$ would yield $d[M,M]=2B^2dt$ instead of $d[M,M]=4B^2dt$...